# Determine all analytic functions $f$ defined in $\mathbb{D}$ such that $f(z)^2 = \overline{f(z)}$ for all $z\in\mathbb{D}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Determine all analytic functions $f$ defined in $\mathbb{D}$ such that
$f(z)^2 = \overline{f(z)}$ for all $z\in\mathbb{D}$.

I found something along the following lines: Let $f = h^3 \in H(\mathbb{D})$. So for all $z \in \mathbb{D} $, $f(z) = h(z)^2 h(z) = h(z)\overline{h(z)} = |h(z)|^2 \in \mathbb{R}$. That is, $f(\mathbb{D})\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $f$ is not constant. Then the open mapping theorem yields $f(\mathbb{D}) \subseteq \text{Int}(\mathbb{R}) = \emptyset$, a contradiction. Thus for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$ we have that $f$ must be constant.

Questions:

- Is it ok to assume $f=h^3$?
- Is this a complete solution to the problem? Even though not all constants satisfy $a^2 = \overline{a}$, we have determined that all analytic functions $f$ defined in $\mathbb{D}$ such that
  $f(z)^2 = \overline{f(z)}$ for all $z\in\mathbb{D}$ must be constant, which seems to me like an answer to the problem.

Comment: Take rather $h=f^3$. Then $h=f^3=f^2f=\overline{f}f=|f|^2$. By the rest of the argument $h$ is constant. So, $f$ can only take the three values of the cubic roots of that constant. Since $\mathbb{D}$ is connected and $f$ continuous, then $f$ takes only one of those values.

Comment: And you are right, you can further determine exactly which constants satisfy $a^2=\overline{a}$. Taking absolute value you get that $|a|^2=|a|$. So, either $a=0$ or $|a|=1$. In the latter case $\overline{a}=a^{-1}$. So, $a^3=1$. This is, $a$ is one of the three roots of $1$.